Check if children overflow parent without scroll
I have a method like that to add shadow to parent container edges to indicate that there is a content to scroll.
export function useScrollWithShadow(
  dir: 'horizontal' | 'vertical',
) {
  const [scrollTop, setScrollTop] = useState(0);
  const [scrollLeft, setScrollLeft] = useState(0);
  const [scrollHeight, setScrollHeight] = useState(0);
  const [scrollWidth, setScrollWidth] = useState(0);
  const [clientHeight, setClientHeight] = useState(0);
  const [clientWidth, setClientWidth] = useState(0);

  const margin = 4;

  const onScrollHandler = (event: any) => {
    setScrollTop(event.target.scrollTop);
    setScrollLeft(event.target.scrollLeft);
    setScrollHeight(event.target.scrollHeight);
    setScrollWidth(event.target.scrollWidth);
    setClientHeight(event.target.clientHeight);
    setClientWidth(event.target.clientWidth);
  };

  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  function getBoxShadow() {
    const isBottom = clientHeight === scrollHeight - scrollTop;
    const isTop = scrollTop === 0;
    const isBetween = scrollTop > 0 && clientHeight < scrollHeight - scrollTop;

    const isRight = scrollWidth - clientWidth - scrollLeft <= margin;
    const isLeft = scrollLeft <= margin;
    const isBetweenHorizontally = !isLeft && !isRight;

    let boxShadow = 'none';
    const top = 'inset 0 8px 5px -5px var(--slate-10)';
    const bottom = 'inset 0 -8px 5px -5px var(--slate-10)';
    const left = 'var(--slate-10) 20px 0px 10px -10px inset';
    const right = 'var(--slate-10) -20px 0px 10px -10px inset';

    if (dir === 'vertical') {
      if (isTop) {
        boxShadow = bottom;
      } else if (isBetween) {
        boxShadow = `${top}, ${bottom}`;
      } else if (isBottom) {
        boxShadow = top;
      }
      return boxShadow;
    } else {
      if (scrollWidth > clientWidth) {
        if (isLeft) {
          boxShadow = right;
        } else if (isBetweenHorizontally) {
          boxShadow = `${left}, ${right}`;
        } else if (isRight) {
          boxShadow = left;
        }
      }

      return boxShadow;
    }
  }

  return { boxShadow: getBoxShadow(), onScrollHandler };
}


Unfortunately, it does not work on mount and to show shadow, I need to scroll which is not a good user expercience because I want to let user now that there is a content to scroll before scrolling. Any ideas how to imrove the code?
